# Does this topology defined by a map into $\mathbb{R}$ have a name?

Tags: general-topology, filtrations

Let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function.
For $t \in  \mathbb{R}_{\pm \infty}$, define the set $X_f(t) = \{x \in X | f(x) > t\}$.

This gives rise to a topology 
$T(f) := \{X_f(t) | t \in  \mathbb{R}_{\pm \infty}\}$ of open sets on $X$, as we can check:

1. Full space: $X = X_f(-\infty) \in T(f)$
2. Arbitrary unions: $\bigcup X_f(t_i) = X_f(\inf\{t_i\})$, since 
   $
       x \in X_f(\inf \{t_i\}) 
       \Leftrightarrow f(x) > \inf \{t_i\} 
       \Leftrightarrow \exists i: f(x) > t_i 
       \Leftrightarrow x \in \bigcup X_f(t_i)
   $
3. Pairwise intersections: $X_f(t) \cap X_f(u) = X_f(\max\{t,u\})$

Is this correct?

**Does this topology have a name?**

It seems like it is the initial topology for $f$ with respect to the topology $\{(t,\infty) | t \in [-\infty, \infty] \}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Also, $T(f)$ is totally ordered, so is the theory of filtrations relevant?

**Is there a characterization of the class of functions $g$ that give rise to the same topology as a given $f$, i.e. $T(g) = T(f)$?**

Comment: I suppose "the initial topology wrt $f$ and the upper topology on $\Bbb R$" would be an apt name. What is the "theory of filtrations"?

Comment: The set $T(f)$ is totally ordered by inclusion and is indexed by $t$, which makes it a (descending) filtration. There might be a simple property of filtrations that charaterizes when they are topologies. Topologies that are filtrations seem to be simple in the sense that pairwise unions and intersections are always just one of the pair.

Comment: Are there any famous theorems on filtrations that would be applicable? Like a structure theorem or some such?